# SQL Server Image repetition

Tags: sql-server

Can someone tell me if this scenario is a bad idea and if so, why?

I am collecting an image from a video stream once every second to use as an icon on a webpage to let users select which live video stream they would like to view. This image is getting stored repetitively in the database.  Would it be better to write and overwrite these images to a system file and select them from that location?  I am using SQL Server 2014 and my thought is that this technique may cause problems with the Log File...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How is your question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay ?

Comment: Thanks Remus.  I missed that one.